# How do I get the sum of the values of a key from array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to sum all of the values of a key "number" from several objects within an array. What would be the correct way to do this? This is what I've tried.

```
var numarray = [{"number":"10"},{"number":"2"},{"number":"5"},
{"number":"3"},{"number":"21"},{"number":"43"},{"number":"30"}];

function Sum() {
  var sum;

  for (number in numarray[i]){
    alert(sum); //sum would be the result I need to get
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use the search ([`[javascript] sum properties`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+sum+properties)) before you ask a new question. There are quite a few similar questions which could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through each of the json object.

Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the values to integer

```
var numarray = [
{"number":"10"},
{"number":"2"},
{"number":"5"},
{"number":"3"},
{"number":"21"},
{"number":"43"},
{"number":"30"}];

function Sum(){
var sum=0;

numarray.forEach(function(item){
 sum += parseInt(item.number)
})
document.write('<pre>'+sum+'</pre>')
}
Sum()
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/evxw9q73/2/)

**EDIT**

When using parseInt it is better to specify the radix

```
parseInt(item.number,10)
```

Using a 10 radix means the number is parsed with a base 10 and thus turns the number into the integer .If `parseInt` detects a leading zero it will parse the number in octal base

**Using Number**

```
Number(item.number)
```

It will not detect any any octal

Comment: What would be `item` in this case? the value of the object?

Comment: Specify the radix for `parseInt`.

Comment: Why use `parseInt` instead of `Number`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this:

Here's how you would normally find the sum of elements in an array:

```
var sum = arr.reduce(function(a,b) {
  return a + b;
});
```

Since you have an array of objects, you'll need to change this to something like:

```
var sum = arr.reduce(function(a,b) {
  return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b.number);
}, 0);
```

Notice the `0` I've added added as a parameter? It's the default parameter and required in this case.